# Why does changing the type from float to double make this comparison work?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, equality-operator

If I just change the data type `float` to `double` in the following program, the code works fine for input 14.2 (and all inputs). However, if I use `float` instead of `double`, the program behaves strangely that, it works fine for all inputs EXCEPT 14.2!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void totalPrice(char, float);

int main()
{
   char gasStation;
   float tankSize;

   printf("Enter the gas station: \n");
   scanf("%c", &gasStation);
   gasStation = toupper(gasStation);

   printf("Enter the size of the gas tank: \n");
   scanf("%f", &tankSize);

   totalPrice(gasStation, tankSize);
}

void totalPrice(char gasStation,  float tankSize)
{
   float amount;

   switch(gasStation)
   {
      case 'I': 
      if (tankSize == 5)
      amount = (5*75.49) + (0.09*(5*75.49)) + (0.09*(5*75.49));
      else if (tankSize == 14)
      amount = (14.2*75.49) + (0.09*(14.2*75.49)) + (0.09*(14.2*75.49));
      else if (tankSize == 19)
      amount = (19*95.50) + (0.12*(19*95.50)) + (0.12*(19*95.50));
      break;

      case 'B':
      if (tankSize == 5)
      amount = (5*77.50) + (0.09*(5*77.50)) + (0.09*(5*77.50));
      else if (tankSize == 14.2)
      amount = (14.2*77.50) + (0.09*(14.2*77.50)) + (0.09*(14.2*77.50));
      else if (tankSize == 19)
      amount = (19*97.50) + (0.12*(19*97.50)) + (0.12*(19*97.50));
      break;

      case 'H':
      if (tankSize == 5)
      amount = (5*79.50) + (0.09*(5*79.50)) + (0.09*(5*79.50));
      else if (tankSize == 14.2)
      amount = (14.2*79.50) + (0.09*(14.2*79.50)) + (0.09*(14.2*79.50));
      else if (tankSize == 19)
      amount = (19*99.50) + (0.12*(19*99.50)) + (0.12*(19*99.50));
      break;

      default:
      printf("Unable to read tankSize\n");
   }
   amount+=20; //Delivery charge

   printf("Total price to be paid for refilling the gas (including GST) is INR: %f", amount);
}
```

Above code doesn't work.
However, changing the data type of `tankSize`, `amount`, and the second parameter to `totalPrice` to `double` from `float` cause the code to work.

Why do the integer inputs (5 and 19) work in all cases but input 14.2 works only when data type is double?

Comment: Maybe you could explain what it means for this program to "work"?

Comment: Comparing floating point numbers with `==` is probably not what you want to do...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: It may be the difference between `14.2` and `14.2F`.  There's enough difference between the `float` and `double` representations of 14.2 that your code using `float` will fail because the `float` is promoted to `double` for the comparison.  Integers have an exact representation in binary; most decimal fractions do not have an exact binary representation.

Comment: These aren't iron-clad rules, but as a general guideline: (1) Never use type `float`; always use type `double`. (2) Don't compare floating-point values for exact equality, and especially not when they have fractional parts.  Even a "nice, even" value like 0.2 is *not* nice or even in the base-2 encoding used internally.

Answer (score 2):

In this if statement

```
else if (tankSize == 14.2)
```

you are comparing a float number stored in the variable `tankSize` of the type `float` with a double constant `14.2`.

Double values have higher precision than float values.

You should compare two float values

```
else if (tankSize == 14.2f)
```

Using the suffix `f` makes the floating constant of the type `float`.

From the C Standard (6.4.4.2 Floating constants)

> 4 An unsuffixed floating constant has type double. If suffixed by the
> letter f or F, it has type float. If suffixed by the letter l or L, it
> has type long double.

That is instead of the floating constant `14.2` of the type `double` you should use the floating constant `14.2f` of the type `float`.

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    float tankSize;

    printf( "Type 14.2: " );
    scanf( "%f", &tankSize );

    if (tankSize == 14.2)
    {
        puts( "tankSize is equal to double 14.2." );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "tankSize is not equal to double 14.2." );
    }

    if (tankSize == 14.2f )
    {
        puts( "tankSize is equal to float 14.2f." );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "tankSize is not equal to float 14.2f." );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
Type 14.2: 14.2
tankSize is not equal to double 14.2.
tankSize is equal to float 14.2f.
```